# Is it bad practice to set a specific timezone for a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I am moving one web-application (PHP 7.3/ PostgreSQL 11) to a new server.

Nothing special except one point : timezone difference

- The old server time was fixed in our timezone (Europe/Brussels)
- The new server time is fixed in UTC

I don't have any privilege to change that setting on the new server.

Since lot of tables uses NOW() as default value for a lot of "timestamp without timezone" fields and lot of queries also use NOW() or CURRENT_TIME, I would like to change the default timezone for the database.

I was thinking to set the default timezone for the database by doing a `ALTER database my_db SET timezone ='Europe/Brussels'`, but I see this note on Heroku (https://help.heroku.com/XKRPVR53/how-to-change-timezone-for-postgres) which seems to say it is bad practice.

**Is it really a bad practice to set the timezone for the database ?**

To be complete, this web-application is country specific, it does not use date/time of other timezones.

Many thanks in advance for your tips !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with Heroku there.

It is perfectly fine to manage time zones with PostgreSQL. All you have to keep in mind is that `timezone` is the *client* time zone. There is nothing wrong with setting a default, but each session should set the parameter correctly.

I think that there are two good architectures:

- Manage time zones in the database and use `timestamp with time zone` throughout.
- Manage time zones in the application and use `timestamp without time zone` throughout.

Mixing these strategies usually leads to problems.